# POST request capture with Mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, screen-scraping, mechanize

I'm trying to use Mechanize to capture a POST request which is not possible via a form, because the form is inside an iframe that prevents loading directly via javascript.

The HTTP Headers are the following in an example request from Google Chrome (notice the `parada` and `linea` parameters)

```
Request URL:http://www.etr.gov.ar/getSmsResponse.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:es-419,es;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:21
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:www.etr.gov.ar
Origin:http://www.etr.gov.ar
Referer:http://www.etr.gov.ar/cont-cuandollega.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.30 Safari/534.30
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Form Dataview URL
parada:4152
linea:112

Response Headers
Connection:close
Content-Length:111
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Fri, 03 Jun 2011 02:35:45 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.1.2
ASP.NETl
```

And the content for this example is:

```
Linea 112N: 0min. 379mts., siguiente 25min. 9937mts. - Linea 112R: 81min. 24349mts., siguiente 101min. 30548mts
```

What I've tried with mechanize is the following ruby script, but I get a blank page in response:

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = WWW::Mechanize.new
agent.post("http://www.etr.gov.ar/getSmsResponse.php", "parada" => "4152", "linea"=>"112")
```

What could I'd be doing wrong? Thank you very much.

UPDATE: Passing the POST as a hash worked perfectly. To render the content then I only had to do `agent.post.content`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The post method expects the parameters as a hash. Try:

```
agent.post("http://www.etr.gov.ar/getSmsResponse.php", {"parada" => "4152", "linea"=>"112"})
```

Comment: I voted this down because there's no difference in the way Ruby interprets parameters between this code and the original code. This isn't solving the problem.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for pointing that. I tested it and you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your original code worked fine. You just need to print it out as `agent.post.content` to see the results.

---

To respond to mightilybix's answer:

The reason your code works without passing a hash using { and } is because Ruby has a feature where if you pass a hash as the last argument of a function then you don't need to include braces. For example:

```
def test(str, params)
  puts str
  params.each { |param| puts param }
end
```

Calling:

```
test("hello", {"animal" => "cat", "gender" => "m"})
```

is the exact same thing as calling:

```
test("hello", "animal" => "cat", "gender" => "m")
```